# How to print notehead with actual notevalues and octaves in lilypond

Tags: lilypond, octave, numbered-notation

I need the note heads to be printed in notes with octave.

The below code in lilypond prints C, D, E, F, G, A, B in notehead:

```
\version "2.20.1"
{
\easyHeadsOn


\clef treble
  <c d e f g a b>
}
```

How can I have C3, D3, E3, F3, G3, A3, B3 in notehead?

How to continuously print C2, D2, E2, F2, G2, A2, B2,C3, D3, E3, F3, G3, A3, B3,C4, D4, E4, F4, G4, A4, B4,C5, D5, E5, F5, G5, A5, B5,C6, D6, E6, F6, G6, A6, B6 with lilypond?

I found an answer below:

```
\relative c {
  \easyHeadsOn
  c d e f g a b c d e f g a b c d e f g a b c d e f g a b

  
}

\relative c,, {
  \easyHeadsOn
  \clef bass
  c d e f g a b c d e f g a b c d e f g a b c d e f g a b 

  
}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your edit at all.  The excellent answer below provides you with a code that adds the octave numbers to easyheads *for any notes you want*.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace, I have found an answer based on the Apos reply below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sort of hackish way of doing it:

```
\version "2.20.1"

#(define easyNamedHeads
  (make-engraver
    (acknowledgers
    ((note-head-interface engraver grob source-engraver)
      (let* (
      (grob-pitch
        (ly:event-property (event-cause grob) 'pitch))
      (grob-name (ly:pitch-notename grob-pitch))
      (octave-name (ly:pitch-octave grob-pitch))
      (note-names
        (make-vector
          7
          (string-append
            (string (integer->char (+ 65 (modulo (+ 2 grob-name) 7))))
            (number->string (+ 4 octave-name))))))
  (ly:grob-set-property! grob 'note-names note-names))))))

#(set-global-staff-size 26)

\layout {
  ragged-right = ##t
  \context {
    \Voice
    \consists \easyNamedHeads
  }
}

\relative c' {
  \easyHeadsOn
  c4 d e f
  g4 a b c \break

  \key a \major
  a,4 b cis d
  e4 fis gis a \break

  \key d \dorian
  d,4 e f g
  a4 b c d
}
```

I mostly edited this example: https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/notation/note-heads#easy-notation-note-heads.

I say hackish because I'm sure there's a better way to convert the `octave-name` into the right letters (A, B, C, D, etc) but for now I convert the number using ascii char codes.

[image]

Comment: Good hack. How to continue. I have asked for 'C3, D3, E3, F3, G3, A3, B3' actually. How to continuously print C3, D3, E3, F3, G3, A3, B3C4, D4, E4, F4, G4, A4, B4,C5, D5, E5, F5, G5, A5, B5 with lilypond. I have edited the qn.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. How are those notes different? How does my answer not work for your case?

Comment: nvm, I see that you wanted those specific notes that you wrote to cover multiple octaves.